# Display rss feeds based on the search values from the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, rss

I have a form with input field for the title and date picker on the left side of the page. And when I enter the title of the rss feeds and select the date, I want to filter the rss feeds based on the values entered in the form and display them in the page.

I am not sure how to add filters to the rss feed url.

Here is the sample code

```
<form id="feed-filter" action="">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="date-filter margin-bottom-6">
      <label><b>Date Posted: </b></label>
      <input type="text" id="datepicker" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy">
    </div>
    <div class="title-filter margin-bottom-6">
       <label><b>Title: </b></label>
       <input type="text" name="feed-title" id="feed-title" placeholder="Search by Title">
    </div>
    <div class="year-filter margin-bottom-6">
      <label for="year"><b>Archives:</b></label>
      <select name="year" id="year">
        <option value="year">Year</option>
        <option value="2018">2018</option>
        <option value="2019">2019</option>
        <option value="2020">2020</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="myFeeds();">
  </fieldset>
</form>

$("#rss-feeds").rss("rss url", {
  limit: 100,
  ssl: true,

  layoutTemplate: '<div><ul id="content" >{entries} </ul></div>',
  entryTemplate: '<li class="feed-list ><a href="{url}" >{title}</a><p class="feed-date">{date}</p><p class="feed-body">{body}</p></li>',
  dateFormat: "MMMM Do, YYYY"

});
```

This is my form and jquery rss, On clicking the submit button, I need to filter the feeds based on the form values and now I am displaying all the values.

Comment: This question is super vague. The first thing to do would be to research forms and how to get the data from them with javascript.  Heres an example to start from: https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_form_submit

Comment: another example that might be closer to what you're looking for 
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp

Comment: I am not looking for the basic form submit or javscript for forms. I need to add filters to the rss feeds. I have a form on the left side of the page and based on the values entered in the form, I need to display the rss feeds on the right.

Comment: So what do you have so far, because you didn't share anything. The base of you question is starting from those two examples

Comment: I am using the jquery rss to display the feeds and I have updated the question with what I have

Comment: If you have control over the rss url, the easiest way to do it is to pass a filter to it
`'rssurl?filterBy=year&value='+$('.year-filter').value()` otherwise you will need to provide a sample of your results to provide a solution

Comment: The url append is not supported by the feeds we have.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a crude approach. It will filter the feeds you have already pulled, so you wont necessarily end up with your limit after filtering.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/31h6t5fs/

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
          integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-rss/3.3.0/jquery.rss.min.js"></script>

        <script>
          jQuery(function($) {
            $("#rss-feeds").rss("http://feeds.feedburner.com/premiumpixels", {
              limit: 100,
              layoutTemplate: '<div><ul id="content" >{entries} </ul></div>',
              entryTemplate: '<li class="feed-list {date}" ><a href="{url}" >{title}</a><p class="feed-date">{date}</p><p class="feed-body">{body}</p></li>',
              dateFormat: "MMMM Do, YYYY"
            });
            $('#filter').click(() => {
              const year = $('#year').val();
              if(year === 'year') {
                $('.feed-list').show();
              } else {
                $('.feed-list').hide();
                $('.'+year).show();
              }
            });
          });
        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <form id="feed-filter" action="">
          <fieldset>
            <div class="year-filter margin-bottom-6">
              <label for="year"><b>Archives:</b></label>
              <select name="year" id="year">
                <option value="year">Year</option>
                <option value="2015">2015</option>
                <option value="2013">2013</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <input id="filter" type="button" value="Submit">
          </fieldset>
        </form>
        <div id="rss-feeds"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Looking at the docs (https://github.com/sdepold/jquery-rss), they don't provide a way to filter, and I'm not sure there is a good way to do that from the libraries perspective. Really if you want to filter this should be done through the request as I mentioned before. Often endpoints will have query params that allow you to specify what you want to filter on (ex. `endpoint.com?limit=10&filter=year&value=2013`)

Comment: Thanks for your support! But unfortunately the feeds are not working this way either. Can you fiddle up and see if this works for you? I might be missing or doing or something wrong. So it would be helpful if you can check and help again.

Comment: Thank you so much! Its not with the code I used and I found out that its something to do with the tool. I checked the code locally and it works perfectly!

Comment: Thank you so much! I found out the cause and sorry for asking too many things. I am kind of newbie to scripting. If you see my form I have to filter using title, archives and date of the feed. Can you please help with that too?